# TypeScript error with Object.fromEntries from fetched data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux

requests = { name: url, name: url, ...}
I've tried to fetch every url and return { name: data, name: data, ...}

Code

```
async function fetchMovies(url: string) {
  const data = await fetch(baseURL + url).then((r) => r.json());
  return data.results;
}

export const getMovies = createAsyncThunk("movies/getMovies", async () => {
  const responses = Object.entries(requests).map(async ([key, value]) => {
    try {
      const response = await fetchMovies(value);
      return [key, response];
    } catch (e: unknown) {
      if (e instanceof Error) {
        console.log(e.message);
      }
    }
  });

  const results = await Promise.all(responses);
  console.log(results); // [[string, SomeType[]], [string, SomeType[]], ...]
  return Object.fromEntries(results); // error
});
```

console.log(results)

```
Array (8)
 0 ["netflixOriginals", Array] (2)
 1 ["trending", Array] (2)
 2 ["topRated", Array] (2)
 3 ["action", Array] (2)
 4 ["comedy", Array] (2)
 5 ["horror", Array] (2)
 6 ["romance", Array] (2)
 7 Array (2)
   0 "documentary"
   1 [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, …] (20)
```

Error

```
TS2769: No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(entries: Iterable<readonly [PropertyKey, any]>): { [k: string]: any; }', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(any[] | undefined)[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Iterable<readonly [PropertyKey, any]>'.
      The types returned by '[Symbol.iterator]().next(...)' are incompatible between these types.
        Type 'IteratorResult<any[] | undefined, any>' is not assignable to type 'IteratorResult<readonly [PropertyKey, any], any>'.
          Type 'IteratorYieldResult<any[] | undefined>' is not assignable to type 'IteratorResult<readonly [PropertyKey, any], any>'.
            Type 'IteratorYieldResult<any[] | undefined>' is not assignable to type 'IteratorYieldResult<readonly [PropertyKey, any]>'.
              Type 'any[] | undefined' is not assignable to type 'readonly [PropertyKey, any]'.
                Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'readonly [PropertyKey, any]'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(entries: Iterable<readonly any[]>): any', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(any[] | undefined)[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Iterable<readonly any[]>'.
      The types returned by '[Symbol.iterator]().next(...)' are incompatible between these types.
        Type 'IteratorResult<any[] | undefined, any>' is not assignable to type 'IteratorResult<readonly any[], any>'.
          Type 'IteratorYieldResult<any[] | undefined>' is not assignable to type 'IteratorResult<readonly any[], any>'.
            Type 'IteratorYieldResult<any[] | undefined>' is not assignable to type 'IteratorYieldResult<readonly any[]>'.
              Type 'any[] | undefined' is not assignable to type 'readonly any[]'.
                Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'readonly any[]'.
    22 |   const results = await Promise.all(responses);
    23 |   console.log(results);
  > 24 |   return Object.fromEntries(results);
       |                             ^^^^^^^
    25 | });
    26 |
```

The only solution I have found is results:any[]. I'm not very good with TS, I've tried everything I know. Sorry for the stupid question

Comment: can you post what you are getting in `results` ?

Comment: @Arjun updated the question description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you didn't specify type to `responses` object, it will automatically detect based on the return from its operation.

In your case,

- you returned a array in try block which is any[]
- nothing is returned in catch block so it may be undefined also

Hence, the responses type would be `(any[] | undefined)[]`

Do something about this, (like returning [key,value] inside catch also) then the type would be `any[][]`. Object.fromEntries() will accept this type.

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from the try catch. When `fetchMovies` throws an exception, you don't return anything in your catch. Depending on your usage whether you need the data or to really throw an error.

If you really need the data even when it throws. You can do the following:

```
try {
      const response = await fetchMovies(value);
      return [key, response];
    } catch (e: unknown) {
      if (e instanceof Error) {
        console.log(e.message);
      }
      return [key, e];
    }
```